# Singleton Java без synchronized и volatile

Tags: java, шаблоны-проектирования, singleton

Правильная ли такая реализация потокобезопасного Singleton? И как его можно ещё реализовать без применения synchronized и volatile?

```
private static Singleton instance;
private static Lock lock = new ReentrantLock();
private static AtomicBoolean flag = new AtomicBoolean();

public static TaxiCompany getInstance() {
    if (!flag.get()) {
        lock.lock();
        try {
            if (instance == null) {
                instance = new TaxiCompany();
                flag.set(true);
            }
        } finally {
            lock.unlock();
        }
    }
    return instance;
}
```

Comment: Enum тебе в помощь

Comment: Я думаю вам лучше смотреть в сторону приватного конструктора класса, куда надежнее.

Comment: Возможно поможет AutomaticReference.updateAndGet. Java 8

Answer (score 2):

Как было верно замечено в комментарии, Singleton можно реализовать с помощью `enum`.

```
public enum TaxyCompany {

    INSTANCE;

    private String someProperty;

    public String getSomeProperty() {
        return someProperty;
    }

    public void setSomeProperty(String someProperty) {
        this.someProperty = someProperty;
    }
}
```

Потом используем

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TaxyCompany singleton = TaxyCompany.INSTANCE;
        singleton.setSomeProperty("Property value");
        System.out.println(singleton.getSomeProperty());
    }
}
```

Такая реализация будет потокобезопасна по умолчанию.

Практика использования `enum` в качестве Singleton описана в книге [Effective Java](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0134685997)  (by Joshua Bloch)

Comment: Ловко придумано. Только что делать, если синглетон должен реализовать какой-нибудь интерфейс или расширить супер-класс? Или просто хочется создавать инстанцию только по необходимости?

Comment: @Sergey , перечисляемый тип в джаве это тоже класс, который неявно наследуется от `java.lang.Enum`. Поэтому сделать `enum TaxyCompany extends SomeClass` нельзя, но зато без проблем можно реализовывать сколько угодно интерфейсов `enum TaxyCompany implements Runnable`.
Что еще интереснее, можно в енум добавлять абстрактные методы и тогда каждый элемент енума должен будет его реализовать. Можно почитать об этом [здесь](https://deepeshdarshan.wordpress.com/2012/11/14/java-enum-and-abstract-methods/)